# Battery to AC conversion voltage question

Tags: voltage, batteries, dc, battery-operated

I am converting a device that uses 2 [C] size batteries (1.5V) to use a transformer in an AC outlet. I understand that the transformer rating should output 3 volts.

However.... I only found a 3.2 volt output transformer in my stash. Can I get away safely with using the 3.2 volt transformer in this instance if it's all that I have and don't want to buy one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A fresh C battery may be up to 1.62 V when new so I see no issues with that. But please measure the output of the transformer when unloaded. Most of them (older ones) only give that voltage under maximum load and with no load it may be even higher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely. Cannot say for certain unless you can get your hands on the specs for whatever power regulator is in the device but I'd be 99% confident it wouldn't know the difference between 3.2V and 3.0V. After all, batteries may come from the manufacturer slightly higher than their nominal voltage.

You should also check the power rating of the device and ensure that your transformer can meet its demands

Comment: Just note that this is assuming that the batteries are indeed connected in series. If they were in parallel which I'd say is very unlikely given the low voltage, 3.2V might be too much for a 1.5V input. If you can see the wiring of the battery holder or use a multimeter to confirm that it is indeed a series connection, please do that